# How to get input as a string which contain spaces?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to make a program that will execute an entered command. I've tried:

```
const char* command = "echo Hello, World!";
system(command);
```

And this works fine. But I'd like to do so that the user has to type the command. And here's the problem. I've tried so:

```
const char* command;
cin >> command;
system(command.c_str());
```

And this also works fine, but only for a one-word command like `cls`. But if I try to enter a command like `color a`, the program saves my input data as two separate commands and executes `color` and next it tries to execute `a` and obviously the output is: `'a' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

So how to save the input data as a **single** string, which contains spaces?

Comment: A _single_ const char? That would be `const char in = std::cin.get();`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you are encountering is that `cin` tokenizes the input on whitespace. If you want to obtain an entire line of input including non-line-ending whitespace, you should use `std::getline()`.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're looking for [`std::getline()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) - this will process all input up until a specified delimiter, defaulting to `\n`:

```
std::string line;
if (std::getline(std::cin, line)) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: The if here isn't right.  Getline returns the stream.

Comment: @Rob Stream is convertible to `bool`. You don't do `if(stream >> x)`?

Comment: That if statement implies that it is checking success or failure.  The stream is always returned, even on failure.  You shouldn't check it with an if ().

Comment: @RobL It **is** checking success or failure. A stream is contextually convertible to `bool`.

Comment: @Rob Interesting... what check are you suggesting?

Comment: @RobL See [`operator bool()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool)

Comment: Check [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline).  The return value is the *input*.  It doesn't matter what you pass it, it will return the input.  You can't check that for failure.

Comment: @Rob You just said you can't check `std::basic_istream` for failure, is that right? And what does `bool func()` do? You can't use it like `if(func())` because it always returns `bool`?

Comment: @RobL That is wrong. You can absolutely check for failure. See [this example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0999d7549f91cdb2). Yes, the return value is the input stream - but the state of the input stream can change as a result of the operation, and it's that state that you're checking in the `if()`

Comment: Crud,  never used that before. I always called fail... thanks.

Comment: @RobL See also some of the answers to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5605125/2069064)

Answer (score 0):

```
std::getline(std::cin, command);
```